# Options below the Appearance menu

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm new at developing with wordpress.
I'd like to know how to show more menus below the menu Appearance of wp:

[image]

For example, how to show the menu option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you registered any navigation location in your theme's functions.php file using `register_nav_menus()`?

Comment: @Patricia Here is the official WordPress information for developers concerning [Administration Menus](https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.